# Datatable - Table header doesn't scroll but body does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a datatable in which the table body scrolls but the table header doesn't scroll. I want to make the table header to scroll as well. So for that I added some code in jquery.dataTables.css file :

```
div.dataTables_scrollHead{
    overflow: scroll !important;    
}
```

But now the table header scrolls on its own and the table body doesn't scroll when the header is scrolling.

Any idea how to get the header to scroll with the body? Your help will be really appreciated!

This is my DataTable code :

```
table = $('#dashboardDataTable').DataTable( {
                        data : dashBoardMainData,
                        "columns": dashboardColumns,
                        "destroy" : true,
                        "paging" : false,
                        "scrollY" : dashboardHeight,
                        "scrollX" : true,
                        "sScrollX": "100%",
                        "bScrollCollapse": true,
                        "searching" : false,
                        "info" : false,
                        "ordering" : true,
                        "fixedColumns": true,
                        dom : 'Zlfrtip',
                        "colResize": {"tableWidthFixed": false}, 
                        "autoWidth" : true,
                        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {

                            var api = this.api(), data;
                            var i=1;

                            if(!isNUllOrEmpty(dispData)){
                                for(var x in tableJson.totalRow){
                                    $(api.column(i++).footer()).html(dispTotalData[tableJson.totalRow[x]]);
                                }
                                $('#dashboardDataTable .dataTables_scrollFoot').css({"height":"auto"});
                                $('#dashboardDataTable .DTFC_LeftFootWrapper').css({"height":"auto"});
                            }else{
                                $('#dashboardDataTable .dataTables_scrollFoot').css({"height":"auto"});
                                $('#dashboardDataTable .DTFC_LeftFootWrapper').css({"height":"auto"});
                                $('#dashboardDataTable .dataTables_scrollBody').css({"height":"40"});
                                for(var x in tableJson.totalRow){
                                    $(api.column(i++).footer()).html('');
                                 }
                            }

                        },
                        "fnDrawCallback": function() {

                            var dataLength = dispData.length;

                            //This function is for appending child data when ever sort happening.
                            for(kp=0;kp<childRows.length;kp++){
                                var childKey = childRows[kp].key;
                                if(!isNUllOrEmpty(childKey)){
                                    var childStr = childDataMap[childKey]
                                    if(!isNUllOrEmpty(childStr)){
                                        childRows[kp].value.after(childStr);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }       
                    });
```

Comment: Can you set up a working example?

Comment: why are you using the scroller option if you don't want the body to scroll independent of the header?

Comment: @Bindrid which scroller option you are talking about?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollY  and https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX